# UNLOAD Redshift: append

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I'd like to [UNLOAD](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html) data from Redshift table into already existing S3 folder, in a similar way of what happens in Spark with the write option "**[append](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-load-save-functions.html#save-modes)**" (so creating new files in the target folder if this already exists).

I'm aware of the ALLOWOVERWRITE option but this deletes the already existing folder.

Is it something supported in Redshift? If not, what approach is recommended? (it would be anyway a desired feature I believe...)

Answer (score 5):

One solution that could solve the issue is to attach another unique suffix after the folder 
e.g.

```
unload ('select * from my_table') 
to 's3://mybucket/first_folder/unique_prefix_' iam_role 
'arn:aws:iam::0123456789012:role/MyRedshiftRole';
```

If you add `unique_prefix_` after the first `folder` level, all your new files, will start with your `unique_prefix_` during the unload operation, therefore you don't need any `ALLOWOVERWRITE`.
The only issue of this approach is that if you unloaded data change, you might have mix schema for your unloaded data.

Comment: I know it's a work around, with `ALLOWOVERWRITE ` we ended up in some situations where the previous unload had more files, and the new unload for the same path had less files, therefore we had in s3 unload files from the last run + some belonging from the previous run, and we just decided to `prune` the path, and unload again.

Comment: I know that feel :( I passed through the same situation. I was very disappointed when I founded out... I use your same approach eventually